# How do I keep Dropdown list's SelectIndexChanged method from firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My code is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but my code is messed up in IE (because IE?). And due to my workplace, the functionality has to work in IE.

I have a dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlistCategories" runat="server" Width="425px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="productLine" DataValueField="productLine" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBound="ddlistCategories_DataBound"  CssClass="myTextbox" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and method:

```
protected void ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((!IsPostBack && !((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString().Equals("-1")) 
            || (!Request.RawUrl.Contains("?")))
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("default.aspx?searchIndex={0}&selectedBrand={1}",
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString()),
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.ToString())));

    }
```

I had to create that terribly ugly if-statement because `ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged` is being called whenever I click this button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmitItems" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSubmitItems_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

with onclick:

```
 protected void btnSubmitItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtItems.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Session["message"] += "<div class='status-warning'>Must select items!</div>";
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("default.aspx?searchIndex=-1")
                + "&searchItems=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtItems.Text));
```

How do I get `ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged`, which I'm not even calling, from getting called?

Page_Load method as requested:

```
if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            string[] recs = MyQuery.QueryGetDropDownString(sqlDsItemNums.ConnectionString,
                sqlDsItemNums.SelectCommand).Split('|');
            List<MyListItem> tempRecords = new List<MyListItem>();
            foreach (string rec in recs)
            {
                try
                {
                    tempRecords.Add(new MyListItem(rec.Split((char)252)[1], rec.Split((char)252)[0]));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "<div style='color: red'> Error: " + ex.Message + "</div>";
                }
            }
            Session["itemList"] = tempRecords;

        }
        lblStatus.Text = "";

        int cartCount = DownloadCart.GetCount(User.Identity.Name, sqlDsDlCart.ConnectionString);
        if (cartCount > 0)
        {
            checkout.Visible = true;
            checkoutBtn2.Visible = true;
        }
        try
        {
            lblStatus.Text = Session["message"].ToString();
            lblStatus.Visible = true;
            Session["message"] = "";
        }
        catch { }
```

I got fed up, so I decided to just make my if statement a little uglier:

```
protected void ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((!IsPostBack && !((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString().Equals("-1"))
        || (!Request.RawUrl.Contains("?") && (((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex != 0)))
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("default.aspx?searchIndex={0}&selectedBrand={1}",
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString()),
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.ToString())));
}
```

Comment: What does your Page_Load look like? Is it setting an item on PostBack?

Comment: I added the page_load method

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure on that. Where the issue is IE-only I'm wondering if IE is somehow changing the dropdownlist but I've never seen it do that so I'm not sure.

Comment: Remove the DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" from the dropdown and instead set the DataSource property + call DataBind() in the Page_Load (if !Postback) and make sure to set the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex to whatever the default selection should be, even if it means setting SelectedIndex to '0'. This way the SelectedIndexChanged will not be triggered from the postback from another control.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting the response after click on that label. The page was reloaded and the method always will be fired. But I think if you surround all the `ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged` method contents inside a postback test, it will not be called after the page reloads.

```c#
protected void ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        // ddlistCategories_SelectedIndexChanged code here
    }
}
```